# Como passar array e mostrar em outro programa

Tags: php, javascript

Eu tenho a seguinte variável em `JS`: `m_aluno[w_cont_i][w_cont_j][w_cont_k]`; Onde em cada `posição` dela `(0,0,0)` eu adicionei um valor! Minha dúvida é:
 "Como pegar essa variável e passar para o próximo programa do mesmo jeito que ela está e depois adiciona-la novamente ao JS para poder exibir da mesma maneira."

Código:

```
    <?php
//Monta o array
    print("<SCRIPT language=javascript>  
             w_ii = \"$w_cole\"; //valor suposto = 2
             m_aluno = new Array(w_ii); // numero de colegios

             w_jj = \"$w_sala\"; //valor suposto = 2
             for (w_i=0; w_i<=w_ii; w_i++) 
             { m_aluno[w_i] = new Array(w_jj);} // Numero de salas   


             w_kk =  \"$w_mate\"; //valor suposto = 2          
             for (w_i=0; w_i<w_ii; w_i++) 
                 {
                 for (w_j=0; w_j<w_jj; w_j++)
                     { m_aluno[w_i][w_j] = new Array(w_kk); } // numero de materias
                 }  
             w_cont_i = 0;    w_cont_j = 0;    w_cont_k = 0;
             w_cont_cole = \"$w_cole\";    w_cont_sala = \"$w_sala\";    w_cont_mate = \"$w_mate\";
           </SCRIPT>");
    ?>
```

Insere os valores conforme o que o usuário digita:

```
function f_inse_alun()
{
w_form ="frm_cad_op1";
w_nome = document.forms[w_form].tx_nome.value;


  m_aluno[w_cont_i][w_cont_j][w_cont_k] = w_nome;

  if (w_cont_k <= (w_cont_mate-1)) // se materia for menor entra
     { 
       w_cont_k++;  // incrementa a materia
     }

  if ((w_cont_j <= (w_cont_sala-1)) && (w_cont_k > (w_cont_mate-1))) // se sala for menor entra
     {                
     w_cont_k=0;
     w_cont_j++;  // incrementa a sala
     }              

  if ((w_cont_i <= (w_cont_cole-1)) && (w_cont_j > (w_cont_sala-1))) // se colegio for menor entra  
      {
      w_cont_j=0; // sala
      w_cont_k=0; // materia
      w_cont_i++; // incrementa o colegio
      }

 if (w_cont_i > (w_cont_cole-1))
     {
     alert("//chamar o programa para mostrar;");
     parent.location.replace("../Array/arrays_2.php?m_aluno="+m_aluno);     
     //vai ser usado para mostrar no outro form
      }

return true;
}   
</script>
```

Verificando-se que no ultimo `if` eu monto uma chamada para passar o `array`, mas foi falha!

Comment: deves rever a tua pergunta porque não está claro o que estás a perguntar. Enviar um array para outro programa? Não quererás dizer função?

Comment: Sim um array. Eu monto um array com 3 dimensões onde em cada posição dele eu insiro um valor, eu gostaria de poder passar esse array! Se caso ficou meio confusa minha pergunta eu posto o código executando!

Comment: A dúvida não é essa. A dúvida é para onde queres enviar o array

Comment: Ah sim perdão! Quero passar o array para um próximo programa  para poder exibi-lo! Via POST/GET!

Comment: @Eduardo coloca mais código e descrição do problema. Acho que precisas `JSON.stringify(m_aluno)` mas sem saber mais estou a adivinhar...

Comment: @Sergio irei postar o código que monta o array e que adiciona as posições para melhor entendimento!

Comment: essa questão já foi perguntada e já foi fechada aqui http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40211/3082 acredito que editar a pergunta original para que entre nos conformes seria melhor.

Comment: @PauloRoberto essa questão é diferente! Pois a dúvida que eu tinha na outra questão consegui resolver, mas essa não trata-se da mesma coisa!

Comment: Tanto uma pergunta quanto a outra eu não consigo entender claramente o que você está perguntando, por isso não tenho como diferencia-las pois para mim está falando acerca da mesma coisa, não se sinta ofendido, eu só estou querendo ajudar no ponto em que você edite sua pergunta para melhor entendimento da mesma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o local storage do javascript, ou então usar post via ajax. Existem diversos meios de trabalhar com este array. Uma outra opção seria você transformar o array em JSON e passá-lo via GET pela URL usando a função `JSON.stringify(seuarray)` como pode ser visto [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295496/convert-array-to-json).

Então para retornar a forma de array no outro lado, pelo próprio javascript é possível fazer usando [este tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20881213/converting-json-object-into-javascript-array).

Vou deixar alguns tutoriais já respondidos sobre os demais métodos de transposição de arrays:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571646/how-to-pass-a-javascript-array-via-jquery-post-so-that-all-its-contents-are-acce
- [Método usando post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16041835/posting-array-to-php-using-ajax)
- [Método usando post e JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19206004/post-array-from-javascript-to-php)
- [Usando Local Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357553/how-to-store-an-array-in-localstorage)
- [Mais um usando local storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22991871/localstorage-save-array)

Comment: Era isso mesmo que eu precisava! Obrigado @KhaosDoctor